# What is the exact command to start the openbox-lxde default session in raspbian?

Tags: xorg, raspbian, openbox, startx, xinit

I am trying to configure my .xinitrc to be able to choose different window managers before starting X but I cannot reproduce the same environment as when I just run `startx` without a `.xinitrc` file in my home dir.

```
case $session in
awesome           ) exec awesome;;
ob           ) exec openbox-lxde-pi;;
# No known session, try to run it as command
*) exec $1;;
esac
```

I am able to run  either of my options on the file. The problem is that when I run openbox I don't enter to the default X session with all the menus and background processes running.

What is the exact command that happens when you run startx (and you have no .xinitrc)?

Is there a conf file that I need to specify to open box so I get the default session?

EDIT: I have checked the system wide file that `startx` runs in the case of an absent `.xinitrc` at home. These are it's contents:

```
#!/bin/sh

# /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
#
# global xinitrc file, used by all X sessions started by xinit (startx)

# invoke global X session script
. /etc/X11/Xsession
```

and the file `/etc/X11/Xsession` never shows any call to start any window manager.

Comment: I think the issue here is that you want to set openbox as the window manager for LXDE, but what you want to actually start from `.xinitrc` is `lxde`.  *"What is the exact command that happens when you run startx (and you have no .xinitrc)?"* -> see `man startx`; it either falls back on a system wide `xinitrc` or it just starts the X server with nothing on top.

Comment: I've checked the system wide `xinitrc` and didn't get any insight as what is the window manager it is loading by default. I edited the question to show the content of it.

Comment: Beware what startx does applies only literally to `startx`; if you are using a graphical login, that uses something else.

Comment: I am not using graphical login.

Comment: Have you looked through the [openbox docs](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Contents) about this?    Just to be clear the "default session" you say starts with no xinitrc *is openbox*?  What about it is different from starting with an xinitrc?

Comment: I think I've found the solution, it seems that there is a pre-written script from the distribution called `startlxde-pi` which launches the full default session.  I still don't understand why it is found automatically by `startx` but now I understand how the X session manager and the window manager are begin called and where are the conf files to play with. Thanks for your help, @goldilocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after fiddling around the system I found that `startlxde-pi` exists so and it is actually what launches the default raspbian session (with openbox). Running

```
xinit startlxde-pi
```

does the job.
Now I need to investigate how is that being called by `startx` when `.xinitrc` is missing.